# Saving AWS instance IP address to variable in groovy script fails build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

**Challenge:**

I have a groovy script running a few AWS instances as nodes in parallel with security group enabled SSH and HTTP. The public IPv4 is available from instance via `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`. I need to save the output from this request to a variable for further usage.

That is, how my current code looks like (on node):

```
String ip = sh([returnStdout: true, label: 'save ip', script: 'curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4']).toString().trim()
println("Status:", ip)
```

The build exits with `ERROR: script returned exit code 1`.

**Failed Experiments:**

I tried:

```
sh label: 'save ip', script: 'wget -qO ipv4.txt http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4'
String ip = readFile 'ipv4.txt'
println("Status:", ip)
```

and now it fails with `ERROR: script returned exit code 1`, too, but in `readFile`. I even tried moving the `readFile` part downwards in code, and he passes all steps after `sh` until `readFile`. If I only run the `sh` part without saving output  to variable or reading the file, the build finishes successful (or as successful as it can be without this information). Example console output below:

```
+ curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
18.202.253.1[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] sh
```

I checked:

- if the file exists (it does)
- the content of the file (something like: `34.244.77.254` without line break)
- the output of the URL (something like: `34.244.77.254` without line break)
- the output of `sh` with `returnStatus` (crazy thing is, I got the IP on console log in this case and build still just fails with exit 1)

I also tried (just for check, suspecting some error in having an IP in return value):

```
sh label: 'save ip', script: 'wget -qO ipv4.txt http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id'
String ip = readFile 'ipv4.txt'
println("Status:", ip)
```

and it behaved as with `public-ipv4`.

**Additional setup information:**

- Jenkins 2.150.3 LTS
- Amazon EC2 plugin 1.42
- AMI images started Ubuntu 16.04LTS, Ubuntu 18.04LTS, Debian 9.7

I'm thankful for any ideas. I'm a bit stuck here and neither StackOverflow nor Google did return any results.

**Edit**

Regarding @JRichardsz comment, I tried:

```
String ip = sh([returnStatus: true, label: 'save ip', script: 'curl -s ipv4.txt https://www.google.com']).toString().trim()
println("Status:", ip)
```

and got `ERROR: script returned exit code 1`, too.

Comment: First, be careful with sensitive data like ips.  Are you using scripted pipeline? What is the result of your curl sentence in a simple shell?  Do you need to get the stdout of command in a variable? Could you try with another http resource like curl ... WWW.Google.com?

Comment: First, be careful with sensitive data like ips.  Are you using scripted pipeline? What is the result of your curl sentence in a simple shell?  Do you need to get the stdout of command in a variable? Could you try with another http resource like curl ... WWW.Google.com?

Comment: @JRichardsz : Yes, I'm using a scripted pipeline. The result from curl in a shell is just the public IP without line break (on AWS instance). Also, I need the public IP in a variable in any case - not necessary from `stdout`. Your suggestion to try `http://www.google.com/` didn't work. I wrote the results as edit into my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

**tl;dr**: The devil was in the details. This is the working snippet:

```
String ip = sh([returnStdout: true, label: 'save ip', script: 'curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4']).toString().trim()
println(ip)
```

The watchful observer will notice, that only the second line changed. Yeah, `println` in Groovy wants only one argument and doesn't concatenate them, as e.g. Python does.

**The long version**: I tried again with this snippet:

```
def ip = sh returnStdout: true, script: "date"
println("Status:", ip)
```

on a **local** machine - just to be sure, `returnStdout` works at all - and got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'println' found among steps [<java stack trace goes here ... ]
```

So the error wasn't inside `sh` at all.

Finally I can say, that the Java stack-trace appearing also while executing Groovy on AWS nodes, might have been helpful in this matter.

Thank you to all that have read this question and have tried to find an answer!